# How to show all the books under a tag and its subtags?

Tags: calibre

Calibre has a feature that lets you create subtags. See "Making subgroups of tags" in the [official blog post](http://blog.calibre-ebook.com/2011/10/calibres-tag-browser.html).

> Now to actually get hierarchical tags, in the tags section of the metadata entry enter a tag of the form MainTag.SubTag. Like in the top figure on the right and example would be Classics.Russian or Classics.English.

Say, I have tags

```
Classics
|__ Russian
|__ English
```

What search expression should I use to display all the books that are tagged with "Classics" or with its subtags i.e "Classics.English" and "Classics.Russian"?

I can get the result with

```
tags:"=Classics.English" or tags:"=Classics.Russian" or tags:"=Classics"
```

But its becomes ungainly if there are more than few subtags.

What search expression I should use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

```
tags:"=Classics.English" or tags:"=Classics.Russian" or tags:"=Classics"
```

can be reduced to

```
tags:"~^Classics"
```

It will show all the files whose tags start with "Classics"

Another variation is

```
tags:"~Classics"
```

If you omit the `^`, then it will show those files too whose tags have "Classics" in them, but not necessarily in the beginning. For example

```
- Classics
 |__ Russian
 |__ English
- Children Classics
- Foreign Classics for University
```

## Solution 2

When you click on tag icon

[image]

two times, it shows double plus sign. This happens only for tags that have subtags.

[image]

When this double sign is on, Calibre shows all the books that are tagged with the tag or its subtags.

## Solution 3

Use following search expression

```
tags:"=.<tag name>"
```

For example,

```
tags:"=.Fiction"
```